# Converter data no formato dd/mm/yyyy para yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, mysql, data

Estou recebendo dois post em PHP de duas datas no formato `dd/mm/yyyy`, no entanto para se exibir os dados preciso converter de `dd/mm/yyyy` para `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Código:

```
if (isset($_POST)) // Se existir o array post, pq ele não retorna undefined index.
{

  $data1 = $_POST["data1"];
  $data2 = $_POST["data2"];

  $busca = mysql_connect("$local", "$usuario", "$senha") or die("ERRO AO CONECTAR AO MYSQL, VERIFIQUE COM O ADMINISTRADOR".mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("$banco") or die("BASE DE DADOS INVÁLIDO");
  mysql_select_db("$banco") or die("BASE DE DADOS INVÁLIDO");

  $pesquisa = mysql_query("SELECT sum(ProdValor) FROM vendas WHERE data BETWEEN '$data1' AND '$data2' AND StatusTransacao = 'Aprovado' ");

  while ($sum = mysql_fetch_array($pesquisa)) {
    $soma2 = $sum['sum(ProdValor)'];
  }

  echo '<b>Aprovado</b> '.$soma2.
  '<br>';

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**MYSQL** -
Pode ser feito diretamente usando a função `DATE_FORMAT()` assim:

```
DATE_FORMAT(suadatadd/mm/yyyy,'%d/%m/%Y') as 'DATA'
```

**PHP** -  Pode ser feito uma *function*:

```
public static function dateEmMysql($dateSql){
    $ano= substr($dateSql, 6);
    $mes= substr($dateSql, 3,-5);
    $dia= substr($dateSql, 0,-8);
    return $ano."-".$mes."-".$dia;
}
```

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: Obrigado @Maison Sakamoto

Answer (score 13):

Se for pelo `php`, Você pode usar as funções `date` e `strtotime` para retornar a data no formato desejado.

```
<?php

    $data = str_replace("/", "-", $_POST["data1"]);
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data));
```

Comment: De 2015 para os dias atuais

Answer (score 12):

15/12/2018 -> 2018-12-15

```
$data = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', "15/12/2018")));
```

2018-12-15 -> 15/12/2018

```
$data = implode('/', array_reverse(explode('-', "2018-12-15")));
```

Answer (score 2):

O STRTOTIME não aceita o formato dd/mm/yyyy.

Para converter de dd/mm/yyyy para yyyy-mm-dd pode-se usar a função `createFromFormat` e `format` como no exemplo abaixo

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "20/01/2021")->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($data));` para horas e minutos junto

Comment: strtotime não funciona para esse caso, não aceita o padrão dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar:

```
$day= date_create($POST->data1);

$now = date_format($day, 'd-m-Y');

echo $now;
```

Comment: Considere adicionar referências a documentações e explicar porque sua resposta resolve o problema do autor, assim outras pessoas também podem se beneficiar dela no futuro :).